# If $p$ is an odd prime and $\alpha \geq 1$ is an integer then prove that $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p^{\alpha}$) has precisely two incongruent solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Note, this question has already been anwsered but I found a different proof using induction and I would like to know weather or not its valid.

Clearly it holds for the base case when $\alpha = 1$, now suppose it holds for an integer $k > 1$ such that $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p^{k}$) has precisely two incongruent solutions.

I need to show that the conditional congruence $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p^{k + 1}$) has precisely two incongruent solutions.

It's a known fact that for a polynomial $f(x)$ with degree $\geq 2$, $x_0$ is a solution of $f(x) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{\alpha}$) if and only if $x_0 = a + y_0p^{\alpha - 1}$. Where $a$ is a solution of $f(x) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{\alpha - 1}$) and $y_0$ is a solution of $\frac{f(a)}{p^{\alpha -1}} + yf'(a) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{\alpha - 1}$).

So, the solution of $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p^{k + 1}$) is $x_0 = a + y_0p^k$, where $a$ is the solution of the congruence  $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p^k$). By our induction hypothesis we have precisely two incongruent solutions call them $x_1$ and $x_2$, hence it follows we have atleast two solutions for the congruence we want to solve for of the form $x_1 + y_1p^k$ and $x_2 + y_2p^k$, and both $y_1$ and $y_2$ exist and there is only 1 of them each, since $\frac{f(x_1)}{p^k} + yf'(x_1) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^k$) and because $(f'(x_1), p^k) = 1$ (this can be deduced easily) we have that a solution $y_1 $exists and there is one of them, a similar argument can be made for $y_2$

clearly our two solutions our incongruent since suppose they were not $x_1 + y_1p^k \equiv x_2 + y_2p^k$ (mod $p^{k + 1}$) $\implies x_1 - x_2 \equiv p^k(y_2 - y_1)$ (mod $p^{k + 1}$) $\implies x_1 - x_2 \equiv p^k(y_2 - y_1)$ (mod $p^{k}$) $\implies x_1 \equiv x_2$ (mod $p^k$), this contradicts our assumption.

My only doubt is did I really show that these two solutons echausted all the possible solutions? if not how can I show it does

EDIT: I was able to show the these were the only solutions by showing that any other 'solution' would have to be congruent to either one of our incongruent solutions.

Comment: Instead of `$a\equiv b$(mod $m$)`, you can also use `$a\equiv b\pmod m$` for nicer formatting.

Comment: It is a consequence of the 'known fact' (Hensel lemma). Since $p$ is odd, the derivative of $f$ is nonzero, so there indeed is a unique $y_0$ for each of the solutions that you want to lift.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist gotcha thanks.